# Rails 3, no local session cookie with :domain => :all

Tags: cookies, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a Rails3 app that uses subdomains. To allow logins etc. to work across all subdomains, I do this in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_myapp_session', :domain => :all
```

When I deploy my app to Heroku, this works perfectly. I can login and stay logged in across subdomains.

However, when developing locally, this does *not* work.

My browser does set the session cookie properly:

```
$ curl http://test.lhs.com/users/sign_in
...
Set-Cookie: _myapp_session=BAh...3ed; domain=.lhs.com; path=/; HttpOnly
...
```

However, my browser (I tried Safari, FireFox and Chrome) does not set this cookie. So, when I log in I get an `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

I've tried removing the `:domain => :all` part, which does set the session cookie properly, but only for the current subdomain. Setting it explicitly like this `:domain => '.lhs.com'` also does *not* set the cookie.

I'm at a loss here. Why does this work in production on heroku, but not locally. I've even tried different servers (Webrick with `rails server` and passenger-standalone). I've also tried running locally on port 80 instead of 3000, but this also makes no difference.

Any clues why the session cookie is not set locally? Thanks!

Comment: Stuck with the same problem, after reading this thread now I'm using this hostname: http://localhost.localdomain:3000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was here, but I've changed 'lhs.com' to 'lhs.me' and moved it below the *official* localhost definition in my hosts file. Not it all works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

When `:domain => :all` is set in Rails 3.0.3, local session cookies seem not to be set unless you specify a top-level domain in the browser.  This may be as designed, though I see no  documentation either way.

So your session will fail when you visit localhost, but it should be set normally at mylaptop.local.  The ".local" seems to satisfy the requirement for a TLD.

Comment: See my answer. I had 'lhs.com', but that didnt' work either. What you're referring to is the TLD-Size, which is 2 by default (domain.ext), but for development you could set it to 1

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in Rails where `:domain => :all` is broken when visiting the site as `localhost` or an IP address:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6002-patch-ignore-domain-all-option-if-host-is-ip-address-or-localhost

It looks like a patch has been submitted, but I can't tell from that page whether it has been included in any releases yet.

As you've discovered, a solution is to edit /etc/hosts to include something like localhost.localdomain or something else besides a bare hostname (like lhs.me).

Answer (score 1):

In config/intializers/session_store.rb set your domain to use all subdomains

```
Your::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                                       :key => '_example.com_session',  
                                       :domain => ".lvh.me"
```

Make sure to include the `.` before the host name.

Comment: Why is that all keys are starting with '_'

Comment: Wonder how I get this to work across different ports. I've got two parts (deployed to different subdomains) running on different ports for dev

Answer (score 0):

Use custom session store config in production only

```
if Rails.env.production?
    Rails::Application.config.session_store(:cookie_store, key: '_my_session', secure: Rails.env.production?, domain: :all, tld_length: 2)
end
```